# How to use JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to be able to use the dates for adding or subtracting but I don't know how to separate the dates from the rest of the data.

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY', 
  function (error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

This is the result it is giving me so far.

```
{
   count:56,
   results:[
      {
         date:'2014-02-04T03:30:01',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-02-20T03:29:47',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014051LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-03-08T03:29:33',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014067LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-03-24T03:29:20',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014083LGN00'
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: { count: 56, 
  results: 
   [ { date: '2014-02-04T03:30:01', 
       id: 'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00' }, 
     { date: '2014-02-20T03:29:47', 
       id: 'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014051LGN00' }, 
     { date: '2014-03-08T03:29:33', 
       id: 'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014067LGN00' }, 
     { date: '2014-03-24T03:29:20', 
       id: 'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014083LGN00' },

Comment: Use normal array methods.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var request = require('request');

request('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY', 
  function (error, response, body) {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);
    var result = data.results;
    for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
      console.log(result[i].date);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = data.results;
var dateArr = [];                 //use to storage date
for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
    console.log(results[i].date) //just print every date
    dateArr.push(results[i].date);
}
console.log(dateArr);            //print dateArr
```

Comment: you are not add anything to `dateArr`

Comment: I forget to add a line: dateArr.push(results[i].date);

Answer (score 0):

javascript :

```
var date = new Array();
var json = {
   count:56,
   results:[
      {
         date:'2014-02-04T03:30:01',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014035LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-02-20T03:29:47',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014051LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-03-08T03:29:33',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014067LGN00'
      },
      {
         date:'2014-03-24T03:29:20',
         id:'LC8_L1T_TOA/LC81270592014083LGN00'
      }
    ]
};
var temp = json.results;
for(var i= 0; i<temp.length;i++){
    date.push(temp[i].date);
}
console.log(date);
```

Here is the sample jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/43hbB/558/

Answer (score 0):

Try [array map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to `separate` the `date` from the data.

```
var data = obj.results;
var newObj = data.map(function(elem) {
return elem.date;
})
console.log(newObj);
```

**Working fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/eey2s68L/

Answer (score 0):

To do any addition/subtraction on dates, you need to convert the received date(string) to a `Date` object first.

```
var allDates= [];
var request = require('request');
request('https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/assets?lon=100.75&lat=1.5&begin=2014-02-01&api_key=DEMO_KEY', function (error, response, body) {
  var data = JSON.parse(body);

  var results= data.results;
  for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
   allDates.push(new Date(results[i].date)); //Pushing date objects to an array
   //You can do your opertations here, but use (new Date(results[i].date))
  }
});
```