# how to use JSON data in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm making an test e-commerce store to learn nextjs and I am having trouble implementing stripe as my payment processor. I'm sending an array of objects to my nextjs api route and I am receiving data that looks like this in my console.log(data):

[{"id":3,"title":"Mens Cotton Jacket","price":55.99,"description":"great outerwear jackets for Spring/Autumn/Winter, suitable for many occasions, such as working, hiking, camping, mountain/rock climbing, cycling, traveling or other outdoors. Good gift choice for you or your family member. A warm hearted love to Father, husband or son in this thanksgiving or Christmas Day.","category":"men's clothing","image":"https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL.*AC_UX679*.jpg"}]

This looks like an array to me, so when I use the data.map array method I get the error .map is not a function. This is also what is recommended in this post [How to use JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144365/how-to-use-json-data)

here is how I am sending the data to the api route:
basket is my array of objects

```
    const postData = async () => {  
      const response = await fetch("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(basket),
      })
      return response.json();
    };
```

this function is called on a onClick in a button.

here is how I am receiving the data but its not working how I expect. What I want is the transformedItems to make a new array from the array sent by the client and used in the line_items param like below. Again the error I get is that .map is not a function. I know that I am receiving  data but I am not sure how to use it correctly

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  if (req.method === 'POST') {

    const data = req.body
      console.log(data)
      
    const transformedItems = data.map(items => ({  
      price_data: { 
      unit_amount: items.price,
      currency: 'usd',
      product_data: {  
        name: items.title,
        description: items.description,
      },
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }))

    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "GB"],
        },
       line_items: transformedItems,

        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

based on the questions asked in the comments when I try the JSON.parse I get this error - TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: Do you maybe need to JSON.parse it before mapping? It might still be a stringified JSON

Comment: when I do the JSON.parse I git this error -  TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value

Comment: you are posting this `JSON.stringify(basket)` and expecting it to be received as an array?

Comment: based off of what I have been researching in nextjs 12+ it automatically parses and I am using 13,  so yes? Ultimately that is why I am asking the question, I am not sure.