# axis error 500 data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, stripe-payments

This is kind of an extension of another question I asked that doesn't have an answer so far. I am making a test e-commerce store to learn next js and I am trying to implement stripe checkout as my payment processor. I'm getting a .map is not a function error. in my previous question I was trying to implement it by posting to the api with the post method and this time I am trying axis.post still with no luck. Here is my last post [how to use JSON data in nextjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754492/how-to-use-json-data-in-nextjs?noredirect=1#comment131933591_74754492)

Here is the response that I am getting from my console.log from the axis.post:

```
{
  body: [
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Mens Cotton Jacket',
      price: 55.99,
      description: 'great outerwear jackets for Spring/Autumn/Winter, suitable for many occasions, such as working, hiking, camping, mountain/rock climbing, cycling, traveling or other outdoors. Good gift choice for you or your family member. A warm hearted love to Father, husband or son in this thanksgiving or Christmas Day.',
      category: "men's clothing",
      image: 'https://fakestoreapi.com/img/71li-ujtlUL._AC_UX679_.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

When I do the .map array method I get the error .map is not a function. how do I use this data if not the .map function. This post suggests that .map should just work but I'm obviously doing something wrong. [How to use JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40144365/how-to-use-json-data). I have tried JSON.parse but that gave me an error as well.

here is how I am posting to the api:

```
    const postData = async () => {  
      const response = await axios.post("/api/checkout_sessions", {
        // method: "POST",
        body: basket,
      })
      return response.json();
    };
```

basket is the array of objects that I am sending to the api.

Here is how I am trying to use the data that is being posted. What I am trying to do is use the data in the .map function to create a new array that is formatted correctly for the Stripe API. I get stopped at the .map and I am unsure where to go from here because I have read what I think to be all the necessary parts of the docs of nextjs, stripe, and axios.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {

  if (req.method === 'POST') {

    const data = req.body

      console.log(data)
      
    const transformedItems = data.map(items => ({  
      price_data: { 
      unit_amount: items.price,
      currency: 'usd',
      product_data: {  
        name: items.title,
        description: items.description,
      },
    },
    quantity: 1,
  }))

    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        shipping_address_collection: {
          allowed_countries: ["US", "CA", "GB"],
        },
       line_items: transformedItems,

        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to receive the `basket` parameter that's why you got the error.

```
   const postData = async (basket) => {  
     const response = await axios.post("/api/checkout_sessions", {
      // method: "POST",
      body: basket,
      })
     return response.json();
   };
```

You can try with `basket` parameter